# WPF でボタンをタッチダウン→タッチリーブした際、想定外のクリックイベントが発生してしまう

Tags: wpf

C#(WPF)にて、タブレット端末で動作する画面を製作しています。
画面を閉じるボタン(×)を自前で作成する必要があるのですが
閉じるボタン(×)に対して「タッチダウン→指を下に移動してタッチリーブ」をすると
稀にクリックイベントが発生してしまい、画面を閉じる際のメッセージBOXが表示されてしまいます。
「タッチダウン→指を下に移動してタッチリーブ」の操作ではメッセージBOXを表示したくありません。
原因や対応策について、思い当たる方がいらっしゃれば、ご教示お願いします。

開発環境：.NetFramework 4.0
動作環境：Windows11

XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontSize="24"
    FontFamily="MS Gothic"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="None"
    UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Content="×" Name="Exit" Margin="0" Padding="3" Width="30" Height="25"
                Click="Exit_Click" TouchDown="Exit_TouchDown" TouchUp="Exit_TouchUp" TouchLeave="Exit_TouchLeave"
                Visibility="Visible" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Right" ClickMode="Press" Background="Transparent"/>
            <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Background="Transparent" Text="test"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

コードビハインド

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{   
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // クリックイベント処理
        private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   // アプリケーション終了ボタン クリックイベント処理
            MessageBoxResult ret;
            ret = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show( "オペキーボードを終了します。よろしいですか？",
                "終了確認",
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                MessageBoxImage.Question);                                                  // 終了確認ダイアログ表示
            if (ret == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {   // ダイアログ展開成功か
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();                              // オペキー画面終了
            }
        }

        // タッチダウンイベント処理
        private void Exit_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Button btnObj = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender; // ボタンオブジェクト生成
            btnObj.ClickMode = ClickMode.Release;
        }

        // タッチアップイベント処理
        private void Exit_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            Exit_Click(sender,e);
        }

        // タッチリーブイベント処理
        private void Exit_TouchLeave(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Button btnObj = (System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender; // ボタンオブジェクト生成
            btnObj.ClickMode = ClickMode.Press;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exit_TouchUpでもbtnObj.ClickMode = ClickMode.Press;書かないと、タッチアップ時にClickModeがClickMode.Releaseのままだったりしないでしょうか。ただそれ以前に、Button.Commandに終了処理を実装すれば、WPFがクリックでもタップでもうまくいくように制御してくれるかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。　　
　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　>タッチアップ時にClickModeがClickMode.Releaseのままだったりしないでしょうか。　　
→操作はタッチダウンとタッチリーブのみで、タッチアップする前に現象が発生します。そのため、タッチアップでClickModeを変更しないことは現象には影響しないと考えます。　　

　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　>Button.Commandに終了処理を実装すれば、WPFがクリックでもタップでもうまくいくように制御してくれるかもしれません。　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　→お伝えしておらず申し訳ありません。システムの都合上、以下の制限があるため、Commandでは対応できないと考えています。　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・クリック操作時：Press時にメッセージBOX展開　　
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・タッチ操作時：タッチアップ時にメッセージBOX展開(かつダウンとアップが同じボタン)

Comment: 環境が無いので確認できていませんが、Button.Clickの処理は一度削除して、Button.MouseDownとButton.TouchUp時に終了処理を移動させてみるのはいかがでしょうか。ただButton.TouchUpについては、事前にButton.TouchDownで終了ボタン上でタッチしたかどうかを判定しておかないと、別の場所でタッチした指を終了ボタンの上で離して終了できてしまう問題が起こるとは予想されます。